# How to show records *only* from current user php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm developing a web app that allows me to generate product orders in PHP. When I first started, I was thinking only about **my product orders**, however, I have 3 more sales representatives and I would like for them to use it as well.

The problem I'm currently facing is that whenever I'm looking for product orders (using an ajax), all users are allowed to see all the product orders. I would like that each user can only see **their* product orders, but I'm not sure how the query should be.[image: Here is a screenshot of how my tables are organized]

What would the query be considering these tables?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**: 
So, thanks to @Nicolas answer, I was able to get only information for a selected vendor. However, the 'nombre_cliente(client name)' from 'clientes' tables is wrong for every row. It is showing **only** the first row. Other information is correct, except for the name. Here is what the results look like now, and how I'm looping through the data.

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Tbdp.png)

[looping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjgZO.png)

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: where do you store your product orders? No table from your graphic is named anyhow like 'product_orders"?

Comment: You have a user table, is it link to the product order table in any ways ? Sorry it's written in spanish and i can't understand it.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm reading your table/field names correctly but it seems your orders table does not have an fkey to the users table.

Comment: @ndeufemia, product orders are stored in "facturas".

Comment: @Nicolas, I have an id_vendedor from "facturas", which is linked to user_id from "users"

Comment: @AlexHowansky, yes,  id_vendedor and user_id. That is how I associate them.

Comment: @JuanBarrera Then just add a relation to users via #id_users within the facturas table

Comment: Then you just need to add a WHERE clause to limit the orders to the currently logged-in user.

Comment: @ndeufemia, Yes. I just don't know how to write the query.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, I know I need to select * from these tables where facturas.id_vendedor = current_user but I also need information from tables "clientes and facturas" But I do not know how to write the query so that my loop to fetch data does not give me all the results but rather only results from a row where the id_vendedor = current_user

Comment: so actually your question is, how to join these information. See @Nicolas answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand, You would need to know who's asking the server for every request. There's multiple way to achieve this and we don't have enough informations about your infrastructure to give you a good way to accomplish this. Are you using PHP session, are you using an API with API keys, etc. Either way, To get only the product order for a particular vendor, you would need to execute a SQL that would look like that :

```
SELECT * FROM `facturas` WHERE `id_vendedor` = 1;
```

In this example, `1` is the id of the connected user.

This request will filter every order and returns only the one that have been done by the user with the id : `1`.

You could also join both tables together and filter by some other property of the `user` table. Lets say we want to get every order by the user whose name contains "john". we would do a request like that :

```
SELECT facturas.* FROM `facturas` JOIN `users` ON `facturas`.`id_vendedor` = `users`. `user_id` WHERE `users`.`firstname` LIKE '%john%';
```

In this case, we are joining both table, mapping every `id_vendedor` to an `user_id` in the user table, and filtering by `firstname`. The `like` operator can be translate to : '*anything* **john** *anything*'.

**IMPORTANT**
If you are doing SQL request in any language, make sure you are [binding your parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nicolas help, I was able to fix my problem. The final query is:
SELECT * FROM  facturas JOIN clientes ON facturas.id_cliente=clientes.id_cliente where facturas.id_vendedor=$current_user (variable that I used to keep track of who is logged in)